# jQuery is not a function in ajax function

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, k2, ajax

I'm modifying the website (I got it the way it is right now, maybe even worse).

I'm getting the "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...) is not a function" on the website, the error appears in ajax function, as you can see on that site: http://4tour.pl/bochnia

I'm using Joomla 3.8.8, K2 2.8.0 and jQuery Easy plugin 2.2.0 (had a lot of errors because of multiple declarations of jQuery all over the site, scattered all over multiple files, and I have no idea where they are, so I installed that plugin) with jQuery+UI fix, noConflict and Migrate turned on.

Order of jQuery modules is: jQuery, migrate, noConflict, jQuery UI (unless I'm blind and can't find a stray declaration somewhere inside the code)

I already tried turning off modules of jQuery Easy (noConflict, disable mootools, different versions of migrate, turning on/off 'Fix Document Ready'), replacing 'jQuery.' to '$.' in that particular function but nothing seems to be working.

```
function ajax_results577() {    
        jQuery(".results_container").html("<p><img src='http://4tour.pl/media/k2/assets/images/system/loader.gif' /></p>");

        var url = "/bochnia/itemlist/filter?format=raw";
        var data = jQuery("#K2FilterBox577 form").find(":input").filter(function () {
                        return jQuery.trim(this.value).length > 0
                    }).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            data: data + "&format=raw",
            type: "get",
            url: url,
            success: function(response) {   <-- Error appears here
                jQuery("#K2FilterBox577 div.acounter").hide();
                jQuery(".results_container").html(response);                    
                jQuery("html, body")
                (jQuery(".results_container"));
            }
        });
    }
```

P.S. To clarify, multiple occurences of the same error are because the little navigation buttons are pulled via Ajax

Comment: Ok so firstly, if the snippet of code above loaded before or after jQuery? Secondly, have you wrapped the above code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: The error is on lines:  `jQuery("html, body")` `(jQuery(".results_container"));` what's the purpose of these lines? seems like a typo.